# SQL update values in one table to match values of another table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables `t1` and `t2`:

```
  t1                       t2
 -------------            ------------- 
  NAME | CODE              NAME | CODE
 -------------            -------------
   ABC | 1651               KKK |  127 
   CDE |  127               KKK |  127 
  SKND |  127               AAA |   66 
                            BBB | 1651
```

I want to update values in column `name` in `t1` to match values in column `name` in `t2`.

In `t1`, `code` values can have different `name` values, but in `t2` one `code` has always the same `name`, but there are more rows with the same `code` because `t2` has other columns which differ.

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.NAME = 
  (
    select t2.NAME 
    from t2
    inner join t1
    on t1.CODE = cast(t2.CODE as varchar2(128))
  ) 
where t1.CODE in ( select t2.CODE from t2 );
```

Problem is that the select to set `t1.NAME` wont return only 1 row because neither code in `t1` or `t2` is unique.

I've been looking all over but all the questions had only unique values in the table they wanted values from.

I think I'm still far from solution, I'm quite new to SQL.

Basically I want `t1` to look like this:

```
-------------
 NAME | CODE
-------------
  BBB | 1651
  KKK | 127
  KKK | 127
```

I use `Oracle SQL Developer`, so I can't use `Select` directly inside `Update`.

Comment: Please remove tags to products not involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.NAME = (select t2.NAME 
                   from t2
                   where t1.CODE = cast(t2.CODE as varchar2(128))
                  ) 
    where t1.CODE in (select t2.CODE from t2);
```

If you still have duplicate problems, you can either add `and rownum = 1` to the subquery or make its `select` something like `select max(t2.name)`.

Note:  You should probably just have a proper foreign key relationship between the tables and use a `join` to get the information when you query the tables, rather than updating the values.

Comment: as far as i know, a foreign key has to link to a unique value in another table (e.g. ID), I have multiple entries with same name and code in both tables, but they have different values in other columns, so i have to have more than one entry with same code, thus I cant link them with fk. Am I right?